# how to show text an d icon on button in win 32 c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I wanted to get both icon and text, so I didn't set BM_ICON on my button. In
WM_INITDIALOG (yes, the button is in a dialog) I say:

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hwndDlg, IDC_CREATE, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(create_image));
```

It doesn't work. The button shows text only. Now, if I do set the BS_ICON
style, it works, but there's no text, as documented.
Just in case, create_image is instantiated as follows:

```
create_image = LoadImage(g_current_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICONCREATE), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_SHARED);
```

So how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is called an "OwnerDraw" button. You can mix text and graphics on them. You provide the 3 button-states and it draws what you tell it.

Ownerdraw Control Example: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/buttonctrl/advancedbuttons/article.php/c5161

The link above might be a bit extreme, but you now have a search term to find lots of examples. I remember Petzolds "Programming Windows" also has an example.

Note that you can make non-rectangular buttons with these. Generally when you see a weird shaped button on Windows, this is how they do it.

Search Example: Win32 ownerdraw button.