# How to put an icon on a text button?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to have both an image icon and text on the same button, like here in Word for example.

[image]

I set an icon on a button, but the text disappears.

```
HANDLE hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(g_hDllInstance,
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP4),
    IMAGE_BITMAP,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
HWND hwndButton = CreateWindowEx(
    NULL,
    _T("BUTTON"),
    _T("SOME TEXT"),
    BS_BITMAP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    point.x - 47,
    point.y - 3,
    36,
    40,
    hWnd,
    (HMENU)200,
    NULL,
    NULL);
SendMessage(
    (HWND)hwndButton,
    (UINT)BM_SETIMAGE,
    (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,
    (LPARAM)hBmp);
```

I have also tried to set the icon on a smaller subwindow on my button, but for some reason my subwindow is not visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show text an d icon on button in win 32 c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439589/how-to-show-text-an-d-icon-on-button-in-win-32-c)

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Unfortunately, the answer to that duplicate question misses the most straightforward solution, and really doesn't contain much useful information itself. It's probably more helpful to have that other Q&A link to this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @IInspectable you're right, cv retracted. And upvoted your answer.

Comment: @IInspectable Perhaps better would be to add the answer there, and close this as a dupe. The quality of the answers there isn't so important. What matters is if this is the same question. If so, it's a dupe. But it was too late. I closed the other as a dupe.

Comment: @David: I would have considered doing so, if the duplicate didn't have an accepted answer already, leading to a situation, where a visitor would have to scroll past the accepted answer to find a better one. That doesn't make finding a solution any easier.

Comment: @IInspectable That's not how dupes work here, as you surely know well

Comment: @David: With duplicates, it really doesn't matter, whether an older question gets closed as a duplicate of a newer question, or the other way around. What's important is to have a link between duplicates. Regardless of how duplicates work, I opted for a strategy, that makes finding a solution to a problem (potentially) easier. This should always be the guiding principle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instructions on how to get a button to display both an image and text are outlined in the [Button Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx) reference<sup>1</sup>:

> The appearance of text or an icon or both on a button control depends on the BS_ICON and BS_BITMAP styles, and whether the [BM_SETIMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761822.aspx) message is sent. The possible results are as follows.
>
> ```
> BS_ICON or BS_BITMAP set? | BM_SETIMAGE called? | Result  
> --------------------------+---------------------+--------------------  
> Yes                       | Yes                 | Show icon only.  
> No                        | Yes                 | Show icon and text.  
> Yes                       | No                  | Show text only.  
> No                        | No                  | Show text only
> ```

In other words: Don't set the `BS_ICON` or `BS_BITMAP` style (but do set the `BS_TEXT` style), and send a `BM_SETIMAGE` message once the button has been created.

To see this in action, create a standard Windows Desktop application in Visual Studio, and apply the following changes:

- Enable visual styles. This is easiest done by placing a `#pragma` linker directive into the only compilation unit:

  ```cpp
  #pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
  name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
  processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
  ```
- Create the button in the main window's `WM_CREATE` handler:

  ```cpp
  case WM_CREATE:
      {
          HWND btn{ ::CreateWindowExW(0x0, L"BUTTON", L"Button text",
                                      WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_TEXT,
                                      10, 10, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)110,
                                      nullptr, nullptr) };
          HICON icon{ (HICON)::LoadImageW(::GetModuleHandle(nullptr),
                                          MAKEINTRESOURCEW(107),
                                          IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0x0) };
          ::SendMessageW(btn, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)icon);
      }
      break;
  ```

  Make sure to adjust the numeric constants as needed. `110` is the button's control identifier, `107` is the resource ID of the wizard-generated application icon resource, and `32` are the width and height of the requested icon.

This code produces the following output:

[image: Image button]

---

<sup>1</sup> *Note, that you have to [enable visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx) for this to work.*

Comment: I have tried this, I am deleting BS_BITMAP from my button styles, but in that case the icon is not shown, if if I send the BM_SETIMAGE message

Comment: @RandomUser: What OS are you targeting? Have you enabled Visual Styles? Do you specify the `BS_TEXT` style when creating the button?

Comment: I am on windows 10. I have posted the code. I have just used it. It doesn't help

Comment: @RandomUser: I verified this to work on Windows 10. You do have to enable visual styles, though, which should be the default for any application. Unless you want your UI to look like Windows 3.

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand. Did it work for you? I mean, my visual effects are enabled, and it doesnt work for me.

Comment: @RandomUser: Yes, it works for me. I can post the code I used as well.

Comment: I suggest to replace `LoadImageW` with [`LoadIconWithScaleDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703(v=vs.85).aspx) (use `LoadImageW` as fallback if you need to target WinXP too) which provides much better scaling quality if the icon does not provide an image of the exact desired image size. At a minimum, use `GetSystemMetrics` instead of hardcoding icon size.

Comment: @zett42: This Q&A is about producing a button that shows both text and an image. Image loading and image sizing is unrelated to the question or the answer. All that's needed is an arbitrary image of arbitrary size. That's what the code does. If you want to apply the solution, feel free to pick your preferred way to construct the image.

Comment: Why not improve the "unrelated" part of the code anyway? For someone who finds this question through search, the "unrelated" code may be even more important than the part that answers the original question. For loading an icon, `LoadImageW` vs. `LoadIconWithScaleDown` is not a matter of "preference". The latter clearly provides better image quality in many cases. In the other cases it doesn't make matters worse.

Comment: @zett42: Why not improve it? Because it's not needed, and doing so only distracts from the code that *is* relevant. If you want to share information on how to properly load an icon, you can create a Q&A to showcase the relative merits of different approaches. In this case, I *know* that no scaling is required, because the default application icon created by Visual Studio's New Project wizard contains the size I requested. So really, why make things more complicated?

Comment: In my opinion, one can make an answer *more useful* by adding knowledge along the way, where it fits. There needs to be a balance though. If one has to scroll through pages of "support code" to find the most relevant part, that's surely overdoing it. In this case I would replace a function with one that has a more readable name and even less parameters. Two additional calls to `GetSystemMetrics` and that's it. I would add a comment that this helps with DPI scaling and make sure that my answer text focuses on the most relevant code. I can accept that you have a different view. Cheers! :-)

Comment: @zett42: In other words: Add 1 line of code declaring an `HICON` variable, 2 lines of code to retrieve system settings, and another line of code to load the image. That is: 4 lines of unrelated code, that *dominate* the relevant code by a factor of 2:1. Hardly an improvement. And that completely ignores, that I do not even want a dynamically sized icon. I want a statically sized icon in a statically sized button. Otherwise, someone with different settings may wind up with an icon so large, that it drives the text off the right edge of the button, making the solution appear to not work.

Comment: Someone with a high DPI scale factor may wind up with an icon so small, that it's barely even noticable, making the solution appear to not work.

Comment: @zett42: That's incorrect. As long as the application does not opt-in to DPI awareness, the system automatically scales the UI. As you can see from the screenshot I posted. The 32x32 icon was scaled to 56x56, due to a scale factor of 175%. At the lowest scale factor (100%), a 32x32 icon is still clearly visible on a 267 PPI screen. I would kindly ask you to keep this on-topic. Neither DPI awareness, nor scaling, nor image quality are aspects that need to be addressed in this Q&A. You can always create a Q&A yourself, if you find it important to share this information.